# Microsoft Access version rules when using TFS Source Control

Tags: ms-access, version-control, tfs

I have a Access 2003 database that I want to store in source control on TFS2010. I'll be using the Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2010. Are there any rules for which versions of Access can create a database from that source? It's possible that Access 2010 and 2007 will be used to edit the source control. I'm curious as to if I should limit the versions of Access touching the source code to just a single version of Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site of MSSCCI states to support Access 2007: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6

On the same site, two other references from users can be found. One is stating that this version also works for Access 2003. Somebody else is experiencing that this version of the MSSCCI does not work for Access 2010.

A save bet would be to start your efforts with Access 2003, or if possible better with 2007. At least do an experiment with saving some 2003 stuff and opening it again with 2007 and vise versa. In time, I guess that support for Access 2010 will show up and you can continue from there on with newer version.

Comment: Thanks kroonwijk. I'll try and stick to Access 2007 for my maintenance work, rather than going between versions depending on what machine I'm using. I can't get this thing to ASP.NET fast enough :)